# How to get average across different models in django?

Tags: django, templates, view, model, average

I am trying to get the average of the rating (found in the review model) for each product across all the products within a given category.  I am having trouble doing this.  The relevant urlconf, view, and template are below:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', 'view_product_category'),

class Productbackup(models.Model):
    website = models.CharField('Product name', max_length = 200)
    website_url = models.URLField('Product URL')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.website

class ProductbackupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Productbackup

def get_avg_rating(self):
    reviews = Reviewbackup.objects.filter(product=self)
    count = len(reviews)
    sum = 0
    for rvw in reviews:
        sum += rvw.rating
    return (sum/count)

class Reviewbackup(models.Model):
    review = models.CharField('Review', max_length = 2000)
    rating = models.IntegerField(max_length=200)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.review

class Categories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField('Category_second', max_length = 200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.category)

def view_product_category(request, category_id):
    allproduct = Productbackup.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
    #get average for each product within a category
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/view_category.html', {'allproduct':allproduct},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))

{% for product in allproduct %}
    <a href = "/products/{{ product.id}}/reviews"> {{ product.website }}</a>: <a href = "{{ product.website_url }}"> Direct link</a><br>
    #average rating for that product
{{ product.get_avg_rating }}    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What's `Productbackup` and `Reviewbackup`?

Comment: Productbackup = the model that represents the product (website). 
Reviewbackup  = the model that represents the reviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will add method on `Product` model to get avg rating.

```
class Productbackup(models.Model):
    website = models.CharField('Product name', max_length = 200)
    website_url = models.URLField('Product URL')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.website

    def get_avg_rating(self):
        reviews = Reviewbackup.objects.filter(product=self)
        count = len(reviews)
        sum = 0
        for rvw in reviews:
            sum += rvw.rating
        return (sum/count)
```

In template :

```
{% for product in allproducts %}
    <a href = "/products/{{ product.id}}/reviews"> {{ product.website }}</a>: <a href = "{{ product.website_url }}"> Direct link</a><br>
    #average rating for that product    
    {{ product.get_avg_rating }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: passing 'allproducts' not 'product' as in your code. So update the view code accordingly. In your code `{% for product in product %}` is using same variable name, which isn't correct.

Comment: I've made the changes and it's not pulling in product.get_avg_rating.  I've included the method in the models.py file (same as where reviewbackup and productbackup are located).  Am I missing something?

Comment: @sharataka I hope there is no typos in method name. May be relevant parts of your updated code will help.

Comment: I've updated with the most recent edits that you recommended, but am still having some trouble.  Should I be including something else in the view to pull in the average?  Nothing displays when I put the line {{ product.get_avg_rating }}.

Comment: @sharataka 'get_avg_rating' should be defined in the 'ProductBackup' model/class. It should be indented one level. I'm correcting my post for this.

Comment: Would you use Reviewbackup.objects.filter(product=self).aggregate(Avg('rating')) please?

Comment: from django.db.models import Avg
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Much effective(without iterations) way to do this is using [aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) with `Avg()` method,

```
    class Productbackup(models.Model):
        website = models.CharField('Product name', max_length = 200)
        website_url = models.URLField('Product URL')
        category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.website

        def get_avg_rating(self):
            reviews = Reviewbackup.objects.filter(product=self).aggregate(rating_avg=Avg('rating'))
            return (reviews['rating_avg'])
```

In template :

```
    {% for product in allproducts %}
        <a href = "/products/{{ product.id}}/reviews"> {{ product.website }}</a>: <a href = "{{ product.website_url }}"> Direct link</a><br>
        #average rating for that product    
        {{ product.get_avg_rating }}
    {% endfor %}
```